# undefined local variable or method `has_paper_trail' in rails 2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using the `paper_trail` gem (1.2.13) After I installed the gem and created the table I have added `has_paper_trail` in my model.

I am getting an error:

```
undefined local variable or method has_paper_trail".
```

I tried even with higher versions but still getting the same error.

Comment: can any body give solution to this issue.., can i install it in rails 2 application......

Comment: Did you try restarting your Rails server?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Rails-App will load the gem?

Are you working with a gemfile, or do you require you needed gems manually in the "config/environments.rb"?

I would try to include it into the "environment.rb" - moving it into the "Rails::Initializer.run do |config|"- Section .

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  [...]
  require "paper_trail"
  [...]
end
```